# NodeJS enable grpc compression on a server

Tags: node.js, server, compression, grpc

I have configured grpc clients according to https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/doc/compression.md
so that their configuration looks like this:

```
"channelOptions": {
      "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 1000,
      "grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms": 2000,
      "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls": 0,
      "grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data": 0,
      "grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms": 5000,
      "grpc.http2.min_ping_interval_without_data_ms": 3000,
      "grpc.default_compression_algorithm": 2,
      "grpc.default_compression_level": 2
    }
```

Then I added the following configuration to a grpc server:

```
"serverOptions": {
      "grpc.max_concurrent_streams": 1000,
      "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 1000,
      "grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms": 2000,
      "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls": 0,
      "grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data": 0,
      "grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms": 5000,
      "grpc.http2.min_ping_interval_without_data_ms": 3000,
      "grpc.default_compression_algorithm": 2,
      "grpc.default_compression_level": 2
    }
```

But for some reason I always get the error message:
"error code: INTERNAL, inspected: UNAVAILABLE, UNKNOWN, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, DATA_LOSS"

There seems to be no clear documentation on the issue and I have already tried different combinations of default_compression_algorithm and default_compression_level on both sides.

Could anyone please shed any light on what is going on here and why server might be ignoring the messages that were sent to him (I have logged the receiving side and it is silent when I activate compression on the client side)

Edit:
Library versions:

1. Client  -

```
├─┬ @grpc/grpc-js@1.2.0
├─┬ grpc@1.24.3
├─┬ grpc-tools@1.9.1
├─┬ grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts@2.5.11
```

2. Server

```
├─┬ @grpc/grpc-js@1.2.12
├─┬ grpc@1.24.4
├─┬ grpc-tools@1.9.1
├─┬ grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts@2.5.11
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: Hm...the server has a "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.2.0", record for npm, and the client - "@grpc/grpc-js": "*",

Comment: OK, and where are you getting that error message from? It doesn't look like anything grpc-js generates or outputs on its own.

Comment: This is the error I get on a client side after I tried invoking a service. The server does not get any notification that he received any request.

Comment: First, your dependencies list both `grpc` and `@grpc/grpc-js`. Which one are you using? Second, that error message does not match the format output by grpc-js, so I do not understand how you could be getting it by invoking a method using grpc-js.

Comment: It seems I got thie error message after I was creating a  grpc.ClientReadableStream<Event> ... looks like we are using grpc library...